# persist in V-ing

Tags: connotations

Does "persist in V-ing" convey negative connotation? Does the following sound odd?

> The detective persisted in searching for the truth.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you saying your example is negative?

Comment: No it doesn't. Whether a construction using this phrase has a positive or negative connotation  - or neither - will depend on the context.

Comment: 'Persist in' suggests some activity is continued beyond what others consider normal. In different situations, or even different people looking at the same situation, that might be viewed positively (being determined) or negatively (being stubborn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, "persist in" + `verb` does not convey negative connotation unless it is used with a negative verb.

Examples:

- "He persisted in harassing her." Negative.
- "She persisted in trying to solve the problem." Not negative.